# Computation of likelihood of a simulated mean value being a part of population of observed mean value?

Tags: probability

Would you please help me to clarify this question: I use a model to simulate milk yield of a population of animal (200 individuals), in each simulation I calculate the mean milk yield (Mean_MY_simulated_i), and I repeat the simulation process 20 times, meaning that I have 20 values (Mean_MY_simulated_1 to 20). From these 20 Mean_MY_simulated I calculated the Grand_mean_MY_simulated and its grand_variation. Thus, if we assume these means (1 to 20) follow a normal distribution then we can describe them as: Grand_mean_MY_simulated +/- variation (I think this variation is defined as standard error of the mean, am I right?) Now, to evaluate the goodness-of-fit of my model, I use the observed data which I am having its mean and its standard error: Mean_MY_observed +/- variation ( let's say population of observed values). I would like to know how would we calculate the likelihood of the Grand_mean_MY_simulated being a part of the population of observed value? Could you please tell me which statistics I should you for this?

I am thinking of applying the z-score which allows calculating the likelihood of the gran-mean-MY-simulated fall into a certain range of observed mean for example: Mean_observed +/-2 variation. However, the z-score calculation process in the book use "standard deviation" rather than "standard error", I am not sure I understand well the difference in using standard error and standard deviation in this case. Could you please help me clarifying that?

Thank you, Phuong

Comment: _Standard deviation_ refers to the population (equivalently to a single observation from the population). _Standard error_ in this setting is $SD(\bar X)$. Often, _standard error_ is short for _standard error of the mean_.